# wait for upload to finish, azure storage account

Tags: c#, azure

I try to use [CloudBlockBlob#UploadFromStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_UploadFromStreamAsync_System_IO_Stream_) to upload a local file to an Azure blob,

```
public async Task UploadFile()
{
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new FileStream(...));
}

public async void UseIt()
{
    await UploadFile();
    UseFile(); // breaks bc file isn't uploaded
}
```

But flow seems to continue before the upload is finished?

How can I only proceed forward through the program once the file has been uploaded.

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: @GauravMantri like this

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. How are you calling `UseIt()` method?

Comment: @GauravMantri `UseIt()` (I don't await it or anything, I just fire it...)

Comment: Shouldn't you be awaiting that? Also, please read regarding `async void` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @GauravMantri well, I want the method to run in the background, I don't want it to stall the current thread at all. And I don't think the way that I call `UseIt()` will affect the order its contents execute in?

Comment: In what specific way does the `UseFile` call break, and how is the `FileStream` created?

Answer (score 1):

Change `await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new FileStream(...))` to `blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new FileStream(...)).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Then the following code will wait for it's completed.

Or if you define an async method like below:

```
public static async Task UploadFile()
{

//other code

await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(mystream);

}
```

and then in the `main` method, you can call the UploadFile method like below:

```
UploadFile().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```